# how can i remove the blank page created during the transition from index.html to contact.html in electron?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

When I click on a link, for example in index.html and I click "contact" which is external "contact.html", the time needed to load the page "contact.html" is to slow. and this Leeds to create a blank page while the second page is loading. 
I am developing on a raspberry pi 3 with ubuntu as OS .

MY problem here is how can i remove the blank page created during the transition from index.html to contact.html in **electron** , any suggestions?

Comment: Your options are probably: 1) optimise contact.html (this won't eliminate the issue but will help a little), 2) preload all the pages in the background and just show/hide them as the user clicks links (might be feasible if you only have a small number of pages), or 3) fetch the linked HTML via JavaScript when clicked.

Comment: @delinear i optimised the contact.html as best as possible, and i have a large amount of pages. But fetching a complete pages with javascript isn t that a bad idea?

Comment: It's not an inherently bad idea, there are advantages and disadvantages, but it IS likely to mean a lot of re-work of what you already have, so it's not something to undertake lightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

**Option 1:**
Optimize `contact.html` to use a preloader (Waiting screen while your content loads) and caching.

**Option 2:**
Use the `BrowserWindow`'s `ready-to-show` event and show a different `BrowserWindow` while the one showing `contact.html` is still loading

**Code for Option2:**

```
function showExternalPage(url) {
    let externalWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1280,
            minWidth: 640,
            height: 960,
            minHeight: 480,
            show: false // -> Don't show it, it'll be shown when the content has been loaded (ready-to-show), show the WaitingWindow in the meantime
        }),
        waitingWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            transparent: true,
            frame: false,
            alwaysOnTop: true,
            show: false
        });

    externalWindow.loadURL(url);
    waitingWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: "PATH_TO_WAITING_HTML",
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Show the waitingWindow prior to the external window
    waitingWindow.show();

    externalWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        externalWindow.show();
        waitingWindow.destroy();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `backgroundColor` property in your `browserWindow` options to something closer to what the end page's color is. The only drawback is you can't set it multiple times only when the `browserWindow` is created.

[Setting `backgroundColor`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#setting-backgroundcolor)